# Nautilus not showing window buttons anymore?

Tags: unity, desktop-environments

So look at [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHZRw.jpg). That is basically my problem. The file operations bar has it's top left buttons, nautilus no longer has them, I have NO idea why. Here's hoping one of you cool cats knows why. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: It looks like you added the experimental gnome3 PPA (?)

Comment: i don't believe i have :(

Comment: What is the output of `gnome-session --version`?

Comment: Oh, and what version of Ubuntu are you running?